# How to allow vim bindings in Android Development Studio(ADS) terminal?

Tags: android, powershell, ide

I want to be able to use vim bindings in ADS's terminal.
I already have this set up in powershell, I use `Set-PSReadLineOption -EditMode Vi`.
I also configured it in my `$PROFILE`
However ADS refuses to allow me to use ESC in terminal.
I also tried using `Set-PSReadLineOption -EditMode Vi` directly in the terminal. However same problem.

How can I use vim bindings in the ADS terminal?